# Why are the wingtips of the Fairchild-Republic A-10 bent downward?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, military, fairchild-a-10

Why are the wingtips of the Fairchild-Republic A-10 bent downwards?It is subsonic aircraft .

Comment: Good question George, but it think you'll find the answer from the link above.